# asp.net development server session not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-development-serv

Can anyone please help me how can I work with 'session' while working on visual studio asp.net development server please? as I found its not working there but working with iis

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session state works great on ASP.NET development server. I'm currently developing a couple of ASP.NET apps and all of them are hosted in this web server during the development process.

Please comment these information:

- Visual Studio version.
- Session state mode (inproc, sqlserver, state server or custom?).
- ASP.NET version.

Also, please edit your question with your webconfig (remove credentials and so, everyone needs to see how your ASP.NET is configured, but not your sensitive data).

Let's see.

Comment: hi, I haven't use " <sessionState mode='xxxx'" in the web.config yet. So, should I must do that to get session worked on asp.net development server?

Comment: I've never tried no to specify session state's mode. It could be a good step that. Set mode to "InProc" and comment again if it worked! ;)

Answer (score 0):

If Session is not working on your web server then you can use cache instead of Session. I was facing the same problem and it worked.

Comment: what the email is here for?

Comment: That's different issue.

Session is used to verify if the data is generated by Server side, and resent from client, hence, if we store the data in cache, the verification will be all passed in any case.

That's different issue, we cannot use cache in the verification case.